# Recovering password on Windows Vista Home Premium

Tags: windows-vista, passwords

My wife's laptop updated last night and it's asking her for her password.

She can't remember it.  She entered a password hint, but that's not jogging her memory.

Is the only remedy for this some kind of backup disc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this utility](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/). It will let you boot onto a reset boot disc, and change the password.

Please note that the utility *does* mock with the registry in an undocumented way - it should be safe, but I would recommend that you backup the disc first. As already answered, remember that this trick will render any encrypted files useless - it that feature has not been used; this should be a fine way to do it.

Comment: Thank you.  After I asked the question here I found that one through Google.  Will try that if we cannot manage to remember or otherwise recover the password.  Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a windows password reset disk?
Of course, Encrypted files will be lost if you use any PW reset utility.

Comment: No, unfortunately we don't have that. Thanks for the response though!